# Python Plotly Express Scatter Plot

Tags: python, express, plotly, interactive, scatter

I want to create an interactive scatter plot; so I am using the `plotly.graph_objects` module.
My data has two columns of about 100 points.
When I make a line plot, I have no problem.

But when I try to make a scatter plot, Jupyter seems to hang (message at the bottom says - Local Host not responding)
It takes a while for Jupyter to respond and I still have no plot.

The code I am using is:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
var_list = ['cloxth1 ()','cloxth2 ()']

for item in var_list:
    stripped_item = item.replace(' ()','')

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=np.linspace(0,len(df),len(df)),
        y=df[item], 
        mode='markers',
        marker={'size':1},
        name = item
    ))

fig.update_layout(title = 'CLOXTH',
                  xaxis_title = 'data samples',
                  yaxis_title = 'mV')
fig.show()
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am using `go.Scatter`?

I tried using px.scatter instead. It seems to work, as in I get a scatter plot. But in the `plotly.express` case I am unable to have a proper legend for `'cloxth1'` and `'cloxth2'`; also, both data sets are plotted with the same color.

How can I get around this?

A few rows from the data:

### Sample Data

```py
# read in with 
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=[0])

# copy to clipboard
,time(s),Filename,time_stamp,time_vector(ms),time_vector_zerobased(ms),cloxth1(),cloxth2()
0.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:03.8,0,0,725.9097285,725.9097285
1.001,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:04.8,1001,1001,725.9097285,725.9097285
2.001,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:05.8,2001,2001,725.9097285,725.9097285
3.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:06.8,3002,3002,725.9097285,725.9097285
4.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:07.8,4000,4000,725.9097285,725.9097285
5.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:08.8,5002,5002,725.9097285,725.9097285
6.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:09.8,6002,6002,725.9097285,725.9097285
7.001,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:10.8,7001,7001,725.9097285,725.9097285
8.003,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:11.8,8003,8003,725.9097285,725.9097285
9.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:12.8,9002,9002,725.9097285,725.9097285
10.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:13.8,10000,10000,725.9097285,725.9097285
11.005,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:14.8,11005,11005,725.9097285,725.9097285
12.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:15.8,12000,12000,725.9097285,725.9097285
13.001,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:16.8,13001,13001,725.9097285,725.9097285
14.003,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:17.8,14003,14003,725.9097285,725.9097285
15.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:18.8,15000,15000,725.9097285,725.9097285
16.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:19.8,16002,16002,725.9097285,725.9097285
17.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:20.8,17000,17000,725.9097285,725.9097285
18.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:21.8,18000,18000,725.9097285,725.9097285
19.003,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:22.8,19003,19003,725.9097285,725.9097285
20.001,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:23.8,20001,20001,725.9097285,725.9097285
21.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:24.8,21000,21000,725.9097285,725.9097285
22.005,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:25.8,22005,22005,725.9097285,725.9097285
23.0,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:26.8,23000,23000,725.9097285,725.9097285
24.002,4DRBUP1N8HB706662_Trip-Detail_2020-07-20,00-04-03.csv.zip,04:27.8,24002,24002,725.9097285,725.9097285
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Which version of plotly are you using? Then if the problem is the legend you can just use the parameter `label` to rename the columns.

Comment: My original dataset has 100k points. Plotly can plot it as a line plot. But plotting it with markers as a scatter plot is what messes things up. So basically a huge dataset is what is causing this problem.